# Limit number of elements from AJAX response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The AJAX response returns a list of `<a>` elements:

```
<a href="/1/">One</a>
<a href="/2/">Two</a>
<a href="/3/">Three</a>
```

How do I select only the first **n** `a` elements from the response?

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/' + page,
    success: function (res) {
        btn.after($('a', $(res)).slice(0,20));
    }
});
```

That's what I'm currently trying but I'm getting a `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression` followed by the whole response.

Comment: Shouldn't the code be `$(res, 'a').slice(0,20);`

Comment: Are you sure there's no whitespace or weird characters, and that the response is valid HTML.

Comment: `btn.after( $('<div />').append($.trim(res)).find('a').filter(':lt(21)') );`

Comment: @JakeGould it's just raw data.

Comment: @adeneo you are correct, it is :lt(21)  ;)  I guess, it could be: `$($.trim(res)).filter('a:lt(21)')`

Comment: @KristerAndersson, that is not how the context selector works...

Comment: @A.Wolff - yup, you add one as opposed to eq or slice, had to think hard to remember that one. The usual suspects are : a string with leading whitespace in `$()` will fail and trying to use `find()` (which the context selector is a shortcut for) to find elements at root level doesn't work, so as long as the string is valid HTML, trimming and using an empty DIV should at least fix those, I think? Hard to tell what the issue is really, we're all just guessing.

Comment: Break it up into pieces and see what part is throwing the error. Do not do it in one line.

Comment: That's messed up I'd say rethink your whole strategy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response had two closing `div` elements at the end but no two openings, so I had to make one:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/' + page,
    success: function (res) {
        btn.after($('a', $($.trim('<div><div>'+res))).slice(0,20));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/' + page,
    success: function (res) {
        btn.after(res.split('</a>').splice(0, num).join('</a> ') + '</a>');
    } });
```

It splits it and only gives back the elements you want.

**JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/howderek/VamZt/**

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is the fact that the context selector returns nothing. A simple test shows it.

```
console.log($('a', $(res)))
```

Break it up into pieces. You need to use filter on the content that is return from the server because it is a list of anchors.

```
var content = $(res);
var anchors = content.filter("a");
var anchorLimit = anchors.slice(0,20);
btn.after(anchorLimit);
```

Other option is to do what you were doing, but wrap it in a div.

```
$('a', $("<div>" + res + "</div>"))
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/83xLR/)